# Check every property with condition using every es6 for object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using react and I have state like this

```
this.state = {
  form: {
    name: {required: true, filled: false, value: ''},
    age: {required: true, filled: false, value: ''},
    dob: {required: false, filled: false, value: ''}
  }
}
```

I want to check if every form field has been filled, I tried this

```
const formValid = Object.keys(this.state.form).filter(o=>{
  return o.required
}).every(o=> {
  return o.filled!==null && o.filled!==''
})
```

I know this is wrong because Object.keys just return the key, I wish the state is array it will make my life much easier, but what if I don't want to change the structure of the state? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Array#every` with `Object.keys`

With `Object.keys` you can get the value by referencing the object that it belongs to eg. `this.state.form[key]`

```
const formValid = 
  Object.keys(this.state.form)
    .every(key => (
      this.state.form[key].required && 
      this.state.form[key].filled !== null && 
      this.state.form[key].filled !== ''
    ))
```

if you need a reference to the failures I would change `every` to `filter`

Comment: this make sense too why I keep thinking every is for array only.

Comment: it is for an array only. using `Object.keys` gets the objects keys as an array. then in the every callback we are getting the value from the object explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can map over object keys.

```
const formValid = Object.keys(this.state.form)
    // map the keys to their values.
    .map(key => this.state.form[key])
    .filter(o => o.required)
    ...
```

Edit: But if all you want is the values, then the other answer is better.

Comment: Why not just Object.values?

Comment: @Zlatko what do you mean by slow? so the correct solution should be using Object.values?

Comment: Yep. I mean, they are both correct and produce the same result. But Object.values is simpler and shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.values(this.state.form)` instead. This returns an array of the values instead of the keys.